# Understanding a json statement

Tags: c#, jquery, json, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

So, I'm trying to understand how to import data to a Kendo UI widget. The widget is a `treeview`. And of course I'd like to do it using `remote data`.

So the website's documentation of the demo brought me to this piece of code to get the data. But I have no idea what's going on. I understand it's a sql statement accessing data. But, I'm not sure about some of the syntax. Like, `?, hasChildren = e.Employees1.Any(), :`, the signature of the method, and the return statement (I get the employees variable, but not `jsonRequestBehavior`).

```
public JsonResult Employees(int? id)
        {
            var dataContext = new Client();

            var employees = from e in dataContext.ClientName
                            where (id.HasValue ? e.ReportsTo == id : e.ReportsTo == null)
                            select new
                            {
                                id = e.EmployeeID,
                                Name = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
                                hasChildren = e.Employees1.Any()
                            };

            return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The original statement was...

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models;

namespace Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Controllers
{
    public partial class TreeViewController : Controller
    {
        [Demo]
        public ActionResult Remote_Data_Binding()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult Employees(int? id)
        {
            var dataContext = new SampleEntities();

            var employees = from e in dataContext.Employees
                            where (id.HasValue ? e.ReportsTo == id : e.ReportsTo == null)
                            select new {
                                id = e.EmployeeID,
                                Name = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
                                hasChildren = e.Employees1.Any()
                            };

            return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Linq to Sql`, to be exact.  The test `hasChildren = e.Employees1.Any()` is returning a `Boolean` value to the (anonymous) result set, named `hasChildren`.  It is `true` if the `Employees1` collection has members.

Comment: The signature allows for passing in a `null` `id` property, instead of forcing a valid `Int32` value.  Apparently that's considered a valid value in this data set.  See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/).

Comment: So would the variable dataContext contain the result of a query? I'm not really sure where the query is.. employees seems like a query

Comment: Oh, so is datacontext the database, or the table? Table, right?

Comment: You tell me.  What is `Client`?  The `dataContext` is an instance of that.

Comment: The original method had SampleEntities() as the class and not Client. I didn't notice that until just now, so I'm guessing it's a table. I just have to figure out the datatype of dataContext

Comment: Yes, you need to know that.  Reading it suggests to me that `SampleEntities` is a class with a `DataTable` member, or perhaps a `DataSet` or something like it.  Making `dataContext.Employees` the actual `DataTable`.  But that isn't for certain.

Comment: Gotcha okay, thank you very much for helping me through that!